# AWS CDK - JDBC GlueConnection - Availability zone ignored?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-cdk

I have the following, using aws-cdk typescript version 1.113.0

```
....
const glueCfnConnection = new glue.CfnConnection( this, 'ocd-glue-rdsconn-dev', {
      catalogId: AccountId,
      connectionInput: {
        connectionType: 'JDBC',
        name: 'ocd-glue-rdsconn-dev',
        connectionProperties: {
          JDBC_CONNECTION_URL: `jdbc:postgresql://${this.cluster.clusterEndpoint.hostname}:5432/ocd`,
          USERNAME: this.cluster.secret ? this.cluster.secret.secretValueFromJson('username').toString() : '',
          PASSWORD: this.cluster.secret ? this.cluster.secret.secretValueFromJson('password').toString() : ''
        },
        physicalConnectionRequirements: {
          subnetId: this.vpc.isolatedSubnets[0].subnetId,
          availabilityZone: this.vpc.isolatedSubnets[0].availabilityZone,
          securityGroupIdList: [this.defaultSecGrp.securityGroupId]
        }
      }
    })
...
```

However the `availabilityZone` seems to be ignored.

That is confirmed by using the `aws glue get-connections` to get the connection details

The net effect is that the connection does not work e.g. when testing in the console. Test connection returns: `ocd-glue-rdsconn-dev failed. Unable to resolve any valid connection`. If I edit it in the console, just stepping through the screens and saving (without changing anything), the availability zone is filled in (I assume based on the subnet?). At that point the connection test works and `aws glue get-connections` does return an az.

Originally I was not specifying `availabilityZone` but that had the same effect.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Changed the name of the typescript file without changing cdk.json :s and as a result not deploying the right thing.

Sorry for that.

Peter